# iterating through NSMutableIndexSet without a block

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

Currently I am doing the following to iterate on a NSMutableIndexSet:

```
 if ([indexSet isNotNull] && [indexSet count] > 0){
        __weak  PNRHighlightViewController *weakSelf = self;
        [indexSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([[self.highlightedItems_ objectAtIndex:idx] isNotNull]){
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection: [weakSelf.collectionView numberOfSections]-1];
                [weakSelf.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]];
            }
        }];
    }
```

I wanted to generate a NSIndexPath array and then reload the whole collectionView at those index paths. So basically I want to call the reload after the block is complete. How can I do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this would be,

```
[indexSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([[self.highlightedItems_ objectAtIndex:idx] isNotNull]){
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection: [weakSelf.collectionView numberOfSections]-1];
                //store the indexPaths in an array or so
            }
            if (([indexSet count] - 1) == idx) { //or ([self.highlightedItems_ count] - 1)
               //reload the collection view using the above array
            }
        }];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If a method doesn't ask for a dispatch queue or `NSOperationQueue` for a block argument to run on, and the docs don't say otherwise, you can generally assume that it executes blocks synchronously.  Blocks do not imply parallelism, and the documentation will tell you when a block is in fact run asynchronously.

`NSNotificationCenter`'s block observer method would be an example of a method that executes a block asynchronously.  And in that instance it asks for an `NSOperationQueue`.

Comment: Exactly! So many people think there is some magical rule that because code is in a block, it's going to be run on a separate thread. "Blocks do not imply parallelism" is a great sentence, I might get that put on a t-shirt.

Answer (score 0):

Build the array during the block. The iteration is performed synchronously (so you don't *really* need to worry about the weak self either):

```
 if ([indexSet isNotNull] && [indexSet count] > 0){
        __weak  PNRHighlightViewController *weakSelf = self;

        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray new]; // Create your array

        [indexSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            if ([[self.highlightedItems_ objectAtIndex:idx] isNotNull]){
                NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:idx inSection: [weakSelf.collectionView numberOfSections]-1];
                [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
            }
        }];
        [self.collectionView reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths];
    }
```

Comment: are you sure it's synchronous??

Comment: In the sense that the code after the enumeration isn't executed until the enumeration has finished, absolutely.

Comment: What makes you think that it isn't?